# Left Outer Join SQL to LINQ Extension Methods

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I been looking for a way to convert this SQL statement to LINQ extension methods but have not found any approach.

```
Select A.* FROM (A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID) Where B IS NULL
```

Should I do the where first, then the join and finally the select. What methods can I use.

Comment: Is that "B" in the where clause a column name?

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin it may help you

Comment: You could use a not `Contains` (or not `Any`) test instead of translating the SQL directly, or just translate the SQL using my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786).

Comment: Does `A` have navigation property `B`? Or is there some relation between `A` and `B` configured in EF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sequence of `GroupJoin` and `SelectMany` methods. I made an example, in which `DbSet` instances are presented with simple collection. Just to make it clear and reproducable:

```
[Test]
public void Linq_LeftOuterJoin()
{
    // Arrange
    List<A> A = new List<A>
    {
        new A { Id = 1},
        new A { Id = 2},
        new A { Id = 3},
        new A { Id = 4}
    };

    List<B> B = new List<B>
    {
        new B { Id = 3},
        new B { Id = 4}
    };

    // Act
    var join = A.GroupJoin(B, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, b) => new {a, b})
                .SelectMany(t => t.b.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, b) => new {a.a, b})
                .Where(t => t.b == null)
                .Select(t => t.a);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(join.Count(), 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(join.Count(a => a.Id == 1), 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(join.Count(a => a.Id == 2), 1);
}
```

Also please take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq) with many examples.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySPDPK):

```
var result = (from A in listA
              join B in listB on A.ID equlas B.ID into subs
              from sub in subs.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where sub == null
              select A).ToList();
```